# Offset Jasper Report Horizontally in Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a Jasper iReport that I need to offset for some printers so it will not be cut off.  How can I adjust my report in jasper so that the report will  be horizontally offset?

I attempted `jasperPrint.setLeftMargin()` but it seemed to have no effect.

```
jasperReport = (JasperReport) JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, map, connection);
jasperPrint.setLeftMargin(80);
if(printExitTicketCheckBox.isSelected()){
    JasperPrintManager.printReport(jasperPrint, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JasperReports offset can be set by `JRXlsExporterParameter.OFFSET_X` property. Below is the sample code:

```
JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OFFSET_X, 500);
```